# How to hide Regions and Themes in the block setting admin page?

Tags: blocks

When editing the setting of a block you can specify Themes and Regions where the block is going to be shown.

I need to hide some Region and a Theme for a given role?
Can I do this?

I tried with http://drupal.org/project/block_access but is not useful for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with dirty fix:

Add body class for required role(s), and hide with css conditions.

Comment: I already thought of doing in that way. How do I add the role as class in the body?

Comment: `themplate_preprocess_page(&$vars)`

Answer (score 2):

it's a bit late but for the people in the same situation :

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    global $user;
    if($form_id == 'block_admin_configure'){
        if(in_array('your_role_name',$user->roles)){
            hide($form['regions']);
            hide($form['visibility']); //for the visibility region
            hide($form['visibility_title']); //for the visibility region
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the Region & Theme output, first locate the settings in the **Block Module block.admin.inc file on line 297**. Adjust region and theme by adding  logic (like an if statement for user permissions).

You can use the following snippet as a starting point or start from scratch if you are comfortable writing it from the ground-up.

Include the following snippet in a hook_form_alter() function.

```
$theme_default = variable_get('theme_default', 'bartik');
  $admin_theme = variable_get('admin_theme');
  foreach (list_themes() as $key => $theme) {
    // Only display enabled themes
    if ($theme->status) {
      $region = db_query("SELECT region FROM {block} WHERE module = :module AND delta = :delta AND theme = :theme", array(
        ':module' => $block->module,
        ':delta' => $block->delta,
        ':theme' => $key,
      ))->fetchField();

      // Use a meaningful title for the main site theme and administrative
      // theme.
      $theme_title = $theme->info['name'];
      if ($key == $theme_default) {
        $theme_title = t('!theme (default theme)', array('!theme' => $theme_title));
      }
      elseif ($admin_theme && $key == $admin_theme) {
        $theme_title = t('!theme (administration theme)', array('!theme' => $theme_title));
      }
      $form['visibility']['regions'][$key] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => $theme_title,
        '#default_value' => !empty($region) && $region != -1 ? $region : NULL,
        '#empty_value' => BLOCK_REGION_NONE,
        '#options' => system_region_list($key, REGIONS_VISIBLE),
        '#weight' => ($key == $theme_default ? 9 : 10),
      );
    }
  }
```